# how to change RadzenDataGridColumn background color

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, radzen

```
                 <RadzenDataGridColumn  TItem="Finance" Width="50%" Resizable                    Property="AcurName" Filterable="false"  style="background:red"  Frozen="true" Title="Price" />
```

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Radzen.Blazor.RadzenDataGridColumn`1[[Goldproj.Finance, Goldproj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not have a property matching the name 'style'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.ThrowForUnknownIncomingParameterName(Type targetType, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView& parameters, Object target)
   at Radzen.Blazor.RadzenDataGridColumn`1.<>n__0(ParameterView parameters)
   at Radzen.Blazor.RadzenDataGridColumn`1.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
```

I tried to give a background but nothing works

Comment: Use CssClass property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Finance" Property="AcurName" Title="Price" Width="50%">
    <Template Context="data">
        <div class="custom-column-bg">
            @data.AcurName
        </div>
    </Template>
</RadzenDataGridColumn>

.custom-column-bg {
    background-color: red; /* or any other color */
}
```

`RadzenDataGridColumn` does not directly support adding CSS classes to its cells via a property. Instead, you have to use the Template of the column to customize and apply the CSS class to each cell.